# To find the solution of the follwing problem related to vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

Please help me to find this problem

Let $W$ be a vector space over R and let $T:R^6→W$ be a linear transformation such that $S=\{T(0,1,0,0,0,0),\, T(0,0,0,1,0,0),\, T(0,0,0,0,0,1)\}$ spans W. Which one of the following must be true?

a) $S$ is a basis of $W$

b) $T(R^6)≠W$

c)$\{T(1,0,0,0,0,0),\, T(0,0,1,0,0,0),\, T(0,0,0,0,1,0)\}$ spans $W$

d) $\ker(T)$ contains more than one element

Do you have a tip for me to solve this ? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Tip1: For a basis of W, how many elements do you need?

Answer (score 1):

$$\dim \mathbb{R}^6=\dim \ker T+\dim\text{Im }T\Rightarrow 6=\dim \ker T+\underbrace{\dim \text{Im }T}_{\le 3}\Rightarrow \dim \ker T\ge 3$$

$$\Rightarrow \ker T\ne\{0\}\Rightarrow \ker T\text{ contains more than one element.}$$

Comment: I can't understand the part that you have said " dim ImT less than equals to 3".  @Fernando Revilla